# Differentiability of $\sin ^2(x+y)+i\cos ^2(x+y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the set of all points $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $f(x+iy)=\sin ^2(x+y)+i\cos ^2(x+y)$ is differentiable at $z$.

Isn't it true that  $f$ is differentiable at all points of $\mathbb{C}$? Because $\sin$ and $\cos$ are differentiable... Am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The function $\text{Re} \colon {\mathbb C} \to {\mathbb R}$ mapping a complex number to its real part is not differentiable everywhere, as is $\text{Im}$. Implicitly in your definition of $f$ your using these; so there your argument breaks down.

Comment: How can I find the set where $\Re$ is differentiable? $f$ will be differentiable at $z$ if and only if $\Re$ and $Im$ are differentiable, right?

Comment: They're nowhere differentiable, so that doesn't get you anywhere. By the way, the "only if" above is wrong: $f$ differentiable at $z$ doesn't imply that $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

To be complex differentiable, a function $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)=u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ needs to satisfy the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations):
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\hphantom{+}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}&=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I thought that to be holomorphic (not differentiable) needs to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations...

Comment: Refer to the almighty http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function. Differentiability is the condition for a holomorphic function.

Comment: No, it's not. Holomorphic means $f$ is differentiable in a neighboorhood of the point $z$. A function $f$ can be not holomorphic while it is differentiable at a point $z$.

Comment: In other words, "differentiability (at all points of a neighborhood) is the condition for a holomorphic function."

Comment: @Talexius: since it is specified that $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$, not $f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$, we need *complex* differentiability, and that is given by the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: To be precise, if a function $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann's equations *at a point* $z=a$, we need a little more to conclude that $f$ is $\mathbb C$-differentiable at $a$ ($f$ being real differentiable at $a$ is enough). There are even examples of functions satisfying Cauchy-Riemann everywhere without being holomorphic.

Comment: @mrf: indeed, $u$ and $v$ need to be [real differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The total differential is straightforward:

$$ df(z) = 2 \sin(x+y) \cos(x+y) (dx + dy) - 2 i \cos(x+y) \sin(x+y) (dx + dy) $$

Also,

$$ dx = \frac{dz + d\bar{z}}{2} \qquad \qquad dy = \frac{dz - d\bar{z}}{2i} $$

Checking differentiability is the same thing as checking that the coefficient on $d\bar{z}$ is zero, if you write it in the $\{ dz, d\bar{z} \}$ basis. Equivalently, you set $dz=0$ (so that $dx + i dy = 0$) and check if the total differential is zero.